# Error al iniciar npm start

Tags: javascript, npm

cuando corro npm start en mi terminal me da el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
```

No se a que se debe el error.
¿Alguien podría echarme una mano?

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu `package.json`?

Comment: Intenta correr este comando directamente desde la carpeta del proyecto npm i

Answer (score 1):

Este error se puede solucionar de dos maneras:

1. Reinstalar **npm** con un administrador de versiones, te dejo el link que explica paso a paso como hacerlo [Reinstalación](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node)
2. Cambiar el directorio donde se instalo **npm** manual mente

Para este segundo paso debes de hacer lo siguente:

- Crear una carpeta para las instalaciones globales

  ```
  mkdir ~/.npm-global
  ```
- Configurar la nueva ruta de **npm**

  ```
  npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
  ```
- Abra o cree un archivo ~ / .profile y agregue esta línea:

  ```
  export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
  ```
- De vuelta en la línea de comando, actualice las variables de su sistema:

  ```
  source ~/.profile
  ```
- Prueba: descargue un paquete globalmente sin usar sudo.

  ```
  npm install -g jshint
  ```

Puedes leer cada paso mas detallado en la [Documentación oficial](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)